# ResultSet incorrect only with TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, CONCUR_READ_ONLY

Tags: java

I have a simple piece of code I have been working on :

```
import java.sql.*;

class ODBC  
{
MyConnection myCon;
Connection jdbcConnection;
ResultSet rs;
String sql;
PreparedStatement stmt;

public ODBC() throws Exception {
    init();
}

public void init() throws Exception{
    myCon = new MyConnection();     
    jdbcConnection = myCon.getConnection();
}

public void runQuery() throws SQLException {
    sql = "SELECT DISTINCT HELPDESK_CASE.INCIDENT_NUMBER, "
            + "HPD_AUDIT.AUDIT_DATE, HPD_AUDIT.AUDIT_FIELD, "
            + "HELPDESK_CASE.DETAILED_DESCRIPTION, "
            + "HPD_AUDIT.AFTER_VALUE, "
            + "HELPDESK_CASE.DESCRIPTION "
            + "FROM HELPDESK_CASE INNER JOIN "
            + "HPD_AUDIT ON HELPDESK_CASE.INCIDENT_NUMBER "
            + "= HPD_AUDIT.INCIDENT_NUMBER "
            + "WHERE (((HELPDESK_CASE.INCIDENT_NUMBER)='INC001001837949') "
            + "AND ((HPD_AUDIT.AUDIT_FIELD)='Assigned Group')) "
            + "ORDER BY HELPDESK_CASE.INCIDENT_NUMBER, "
            + "HPD_AUDIT.AUDIT_DATE"; 
    stmt = jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(sql,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE );
    rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
        System.out.println("Something is here");
    }
}

public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception 
{
    ODBC odbc;
    odbc = new ODBC();
    odbc.runQuery();
}

class MyConnection {
    public Connection getConnection() throws Exception 
    {
        String URL = "jdbc:odbc:corpp05";
        Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, "remro", "*****"); 
        return c;
    }
}
}
```

I cannot figure out the following behavior.

1. I run this query in MySQL as well as Access using the same JDBC driver and they return nothing (as they should return NOTHING as the incident number being queried does not exist).
2. I need the ability in other areas of this program (outside of this sample snip) to call *resultSet.previous() resultSet.beforeFirst()* etc. and therefor need to be able to SCROLL forwards and backwards.
3. When I use the preparedStatement as follows:

   *stmt = jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(sql);*

The while loop is never executed as is expected behavior but when I use the preparedStatement as follows:

```
stmt = jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(sql,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE );
```

(Which I need since I need the TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE) The while loop IS executed and "Something is here" is printed.

What am I missing here? I feel like it is relatively obvious I need to just take a step back and have other eyes on this I believe. Appreciate the help.

Cmres

Comment: Have you tried this code for Oracle ?

Comment: Yes this code has been tried for Oracle and produces the same output with the error. Thoughts?

Comment: Well I have executed the same syntax of codes on oracle for an empty table using "thin" driver but in my case `rs.next()` is returning `false`...!!!! **Note:** I have used The same type of result set as you have used in your code...What might be possible is that there might be some uncommitted data in your table and the Connection's transaction isolation level might be set to `Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED` which is leading to the dirty reads by your `ResultSet`. If you could put your complete code then i would be able to assist you better..

Comment: Try your code using "thin" driver . And if possible can you tell me the type of transaction isolation level exhibited by Connection object? It can be retrieved using `con.getTransactionIsolation()`..

Comment: Hi Vishal - so the above code IS my full code as I wrote this program specifically to produce the error. jdbc.getTransactionIsolation() returns 2 ... also I am using Eclipse at the moment and not too sure how to run as 'thin' driver. Do I have to download the driver and set up this as a new ODBC connection? Thank you very much for your help!!!!!!!

Comment: Note maybe I am using a thin driver already and there is a way to check?

Comment: you are not using thin driver. It can be confirmed from your code. The url that you are using : `String URL = "jdbc:odbc:corpp05";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download `thin` driver from oracle site most suitable for the version of oracle that you are using. Add that `jar` file in the eclipse external jar files archive.
After all set up is done:
you can make connection as follows:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());                         
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","user","****");
```

Since `jdbc.getTransactionIsolation()` returns 2 in your case so the possibility of dirty reads is eliminated.

I hope changing driver would solve your problem.

**EDIT**
Read [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21454_01/html/821-2576/dbadapt_jdbcodbc_c.html) about the `JDBC-ODBC` driver as postulated on `Oracle` Website . After some line while describing about `JDBC-ODBC` driver it tells the following cons:

> **Cons**: Not for large-scale applications. Performance suffers because
>   there’s some overhead associated with the translation work to go from
>   JDBC to ODBC. **Doesn’t support all the features of Java. User is
>   limited by the functionality of the underlying ODBC driver.**

So it provides enough reason to believe that some critical issues might suffer when the application is solely based on `JDBC-ODBC` driver for implementing database transactions or other important database functionality via the sensitive API provided by `java.sql` package.

Comment: Hi Vishal ... Sure enough this worked for me. For those having this same problem please install the jar file, add to external libs, use getConnection with "jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOST:PORT:SID" syntax. This info can be found in your tnsnames.ora files. .... As a side note first of all thank you very much. Out of curiosity how did you know this was the problem? I would like to understand why this behavior was exhibited.

Comment: I am glad that it fixed the unexpected error that you were getting.. And regarding how i came to know about this problem ... It is just what I have experienced while working on real time projects . Sometimes a complex application that is working perfectly using `thin` driver provides unexpected exceptions and results with `JDBC-ODBC` driver. So I strongly discourage the use of JDBC-ODBC bridge until and unless The huge chunk project is already built on this technology. I hope this satisfied some part of your curiosity. ;)

Comment: And Regarding Why this behaviour exhibited..It might be the implementation level error in `ODBC driver` itself since it is written completely in native language so there might be some invalid or incomplete translation of Java API calls into ODBC function calls. If you wish to do more research Play with the options provide in `Oracle ODBC Driver Configuration box` when you create Datasource for JDBC-ODBC bridge and let me know too..;)